# What would be the XPATH expression to select all Checked Nodes of a TreeView?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, treeview

Here is my XML :

```
<Tree CheckBoxes="True" CheckChildNodes="True" TriStateCheckBoxes="True" MultipleSelect="True" EnableAjaxSkinRendering="False" BorderStyle="Inset" Height="100%"  Width="99%" RenderMode="Lightweight">
<Node Text="Consumer" Value="79" Expanded="True" Checked="True" >
  <Node Text="BASIC" Value="7983" Expanded="True" Checked="True" >
    <Node Text="RED" Value="7983BL" Checked="True" >
      <Node Text="E17" Value="906268" Checked="True"  />
      <Node Text="W57" Value="906390" />
    </Node>
    <Node Text="BLUE" Value="7983CG" >
      <Node Text="T2T" Value="906359"  />
    </Node>
    <Node Text="GREEN" Value="7983GO" >
      <Node Text="VCR" Value="906386"  />
    </Node>
    <Node Text="WHITE" Value="7983GP" Checked="True" >
      <Node Text="2B3" Value="906246" Checked="True"  />
    </Node>
  </Node>
  <Node Text="ENHANCED" Value="7984" Checked="True" >
    <Node Text="PURPLE" Value="7984CN" Checked="True" >
      <Node Text="V8Q" Value="906588" Checked="True"  />
      <Node Text="V8R" Value="906589"  />
      <Node Text="V8S" Value="906590" Checked="True"  />
    </Node>
    <Node Text="ORANGE" Value="7984CV" >
      <Node Text="3A5" Value="906408"  />
    </Node>
  </Node>
</Node>
```

In this XML, if any child node has attribute Checked="True" then its Parent Node would also have Checked="True". I wanted the XPath Expression to exclude all nodes that do not have attribute Checked="True" regardless of the Node Level.

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
xml.Root.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(node =>
{
  try
  {
    return node.Attribute("Checked").Value.ToString() != "True";
  }
  catch
  {
    //no attribute @Checked 
    return true;
  }
}).Remove();
```

Comment: @OscarMederos XQuery. OP asked for an XPath expression, but tagged this as XQuery. XPath isn't really suitable for rebuilding XML. XSLT would be ideal.

Comment: @OscarMederos :) Some folks are really sensitive to the rules.

Comment: Hi, its actually in an asp.net application i'm building using c#. I have the treeview exported in XML, which i want to import in another Treeview after filtering the items that are not checked. Please suggest a C# equivalent !

Comment: @user2089165 This C# answer should solve your problem. Also, please remove the XQuery tag from your question, since it's not a viable language for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given that, i wanted to remove the nodes that did not contain the 'Checked' attribute at all, I found a much faster way :

XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
xml.Root.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(node => node.Attribute("Checked") = null).Remove();